# Binary to base 4

Tags: binary

How would I convert a number from binary to base 4 `without using extra space`? For e.g. if binary is 1010 then it would be 22 in base 4? I would like to have the algorithm rather than doing it by some in built functions and what about if I add a condition that I don't have to generate any string as output. I have to use the given string space to do that.

Comment: I tried starting from last means the least significant bit but I was not able to do this without using extra space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's Integer class has this feature built in (checkout this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858122/16959)).  It's called the radix property of [parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29).  Note that its important to understand that this is limited to radix vlaues between a [MIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MIN_RADIX) and [MAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX) radix value in the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class so don't expect to convert numbers to base 1024 without a little effort.

For your question you can do this:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("1010", 2); //From Binary
String base4value = Integer.toString(value, 4); //To base 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 1010 in binary is 22 in base 4. It is simple, because 4 is power of 2, therefore the conversion is simply 10 = 2, 10 = 2 -> 22. Much like one byte is two hexadecimal digits.