# Base 4 to binary conversion in java

Tags: java

Can somebody please tell me the code to convert Base 4 to binary in java. What I tried is below but it is giving wrong output

```
        String l=list.get(y);
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(l);
        System.out.println("foo: "+foo);
        C=Integer.toBinaryString(foo);
        System.out.println(C);
```

Comment: [`Integer.toString(foo, 4)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805946/binary-to-base-4

Comment: in this case output and input are same... its not converting it into binary